# Getting a strange exception at app startup

Tags: java, android

I am getting a random exception when starting the app, here is the logcat detail:

```
2020-09-23 17:29:37.062 28153-28184/com.packageName A/art: art/runtime/stack.cc:848] Check failed: instrumentation_frame.method_ == GetMethod() (instrumentation_frame.method_=0x6fb16068, GetMethod()=0x6f9c3e20) Expected: java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() Found: <runtime method>.<runtime internal callee-save reference and argument registers method><no signature>
2020-09-23 17:29:37.063 28153-28184/com.packageName A/art: art/runtime/stack.cc:848] Check failed: instrumentation_frame.method_ == GetMethod() (instrumentation_frame.method_=0x6fb16068, GetMethod()=0x6f9c3e20) Expected: java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() Found: <runtime method>.<runtime internal callee-save reference and argument registers method><no signature>
2020-09-23 17:29:37.063 28153-28184/com.packageName A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:423] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!
2020-09-23 17:29:37.063 28153-28184/com.packageName A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:423] 
2020-09-23 17:29:37.067 28153-28184/com.packageName A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 28184 (Measurement Wor)
```

In the log, there are no references for launcher activity or application, if some code is needed let me know I will add it.

Comment: You are starting the application in debug mode or normal start up ? Also try removing the existing application jar/war if any from target and remove all the breakpoints in your application if any  and then clean build first then try to run the application again.

Comment: @Som No, not in debug mode.

Comment: Did you try the options.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to resolve your issue :

```
 1. Disable Instant Run
 2. Remove all the breakpoints in your application.
 3. Clean Build.
```

Comment: Okay, I will try this and let you know if issues occur again.